# Which CentOS 7 package provides the "boot" manpage?

Tags: centos, boot, man

On my CentOS 7.7.1908, the manpage for `boot` (describing the system boot process) is not installed. How to find which package provides it?

`yum whatprovides /usr/share/man/man7/boot.7.gz` returns no results.

The `bootup` manpage is installed from the base repo and references the manpage `boot(7)` in the SEE ALSO section.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `boot(7)` manpage is provided by the [man-pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/boot.7.html) project. In CentOS, this is packaged as `man-pages`, but a few man pages which are considered irrelevant for CentOS are excluded, [including `boot(7)`](https://git.centos.org/rpms/man-pages/blob/c7/f/SPECS/man-pages.spec#_79). `boot(7)` is considered irrelevant because it describes the System V-style boot process (using `inittab` and boot scripts).

This does mean that CentOS (and RHEL, and Fedora) should patch out the reference to the man page...

Answer (score 6):

That manual was removed from the CentOS `man-pages` package in 2014 [when CentOS switched to using systemd](https://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes/CentOS7.1406?highlight=%28systemd#head-f4437b9c31dbfdbed738b2891645557eff0d94c9).  From the changelog at https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/man-pages-3.53-5.el7.noarch.rpm.html:

```
2014-02-11 - Peter Schiffer  - 3.53-5
- resolves: #1058101
added note about default values to the nscd.conf(5) man page
- resolves: #1059829
added three pthread_mutex* man pages from POSIX.1-2008
- resolves: #1062906
removed boot(7) man page
```

The resolved bug number references [Red Hat’s bug tracker](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1062906) but the bug isn’t public.